# Cannot Install Net Framework 3.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, installation

I have been running net framework 4.0. When I look at IIS, I can see that I have 1.0, 2.0 and 4.0 installed. I have to install 3.5 because I have a web site that is not ready to upgrade to 4.0.

When I try to install 3.5 I get an error, right after I accepting the agreement, it says download complete and then setup error.

Any thoughts? Can I install 3.5 over 4.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post the error that you are receiving. We will likely not be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: They should be able to co-exist

Comment: throw in your dialog box, what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking in IIS, **you will never see ASP.NET 3.0 and 3.5.**

.NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 never updated the ASP.NET version -- they were extensions to .NET 2.0

Here is a [post on Scott Hanselman's blog explaining this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx).

Comment: My problem was that 3.5 was already installed. Dan gave me the answer I needed that I won't see 3.0 or 3.5.